# Cultural fair IQ question of crosses with each line being styled (thin, thick, wavy)

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

[image]

I've been looking at it for quite some time, but there seems to be no definite pattern. All I can think of is arbitrary nonsense, so you can just as well say it's the 1st shape, because of a random / unrepeated doubling of the shape above it.

Are there hidden assumptions I'm not familiar with in cultural fair IQ tests? Why is it that the pattern that is correct the correct pattern rather than another?

Is it that you need to work on a process of elimination of the possible given shapes, finding an arbitrary rule which is not equivalently viable as any other of the possible shapes, even though it itself is no better a fit than any other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> [image: 1]

because

> there are three distinct shapes: a line, a rectangle, and a "squiggle." They can each be oriented vertically or horizontally. In the given images, the line appears 3 times vertically and horizontally; the rectangle appears 3 times vertically and twice horizontally; and the squiggle appears 3 times horizontally and twice vertically. Therefore the combination that is missing from the set is a figure that has a horizontal rectangle and a vertical squiggle.

Comment: for some reason, I was trying to link them into a series of figures rather than a series of independent shapes. so I had the hidden assumption, not the test

Answer (score 2):

I have the same answer as SQLnoob:

> [image: 1]

But with different reasoning:

> Consider each column of three figures separately.
>  In each column every symbol appears once as a horizontal and once as a vertical. (Or, equivalently, the bottom figure contains the symbols that do not appear in the top two figures.)
>
>  E.g. In the first column, we have:
>  Vertical: line, box, squiggle  -  one of each
>  Horizontal: box, line, squiggle  -  one of each
>
>  So in the third column we have:
>  Vertical: box, line, missing **squiggle**
>  Horizontal: squiggle, line, missing **box**